# How can I calculate the suction of an eductor?

Tags: fluid, air

I am very interested in eductors and want to know how to calculate the suction power of one. I know it involves equations from the venturi principle and also Bernoulli's equation, but I'm not sure how to fit them together. I want to be able to enter these equations into a spreadsheet and then fiddle with the numbers, so for instance if I change the area of the nozzle orifice and the velocity of the motive fluid, how it'll effect the suction power. I've tried looking online and have found bits and pieces but am having trouble fitting them together. The best I've come up with is asking ChatGPT what equations are necessary to calculate the suction power, and I got these ones below. The problem is, I have no idea if it's correct or not. Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the equations ChatGPT gave me, for calculating the suction power of an eductor:

Q = A1 * V1

P2 = P1 - (0.5 * ρ * V1^2)

F = P2 * A2

SP = F / Q

where:

Q = flow rate of motive fluid (m³/s)

A1 = area of the nozzle orifice (m²)

V1 = velocity of the motive fluid at the nozzle (m/s)

P1 = pressure of the motive fluid before the nozzle (Pa)

ρ = density of the motive fluid (kg/m³)

P2 = pressure of the entrained fluid at the suction port (Pa)

A2 = area of the suction port (m²)

F = force exerted on the entrained fluid (N)

SP = suction power (Pa/m³)